# how to fix an error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me with this error:

> Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'c FROM oc_coupon c LEFT JOIN oc_cheaper_order_coupons coc using(coupon_id) WHER' at line 1
>   Error No: 1064
>   `DELETE oc_coupon c FROM oc_coupon c LEFT JOIN oc_cheaper_order_coupons coc using(coupon_id) WHERE coc.order_id = '26' in /home/blablabl/public_html/shop/system/database/mysql.php on line 50`

The code is:

```
class ModelSaleCheaper extends Model {
    public function deleteOrder($order_id) {
        $this->db->query("DELETE " . DB_PREFIX . "coupon c FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "coupon c LEFT JOIN  " . DB_PREFIX . "cheaper_order_coupons coc using(coupon_id) WHERE coc.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE " . DB_PREFIX . "coupon_product cp FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "coupon_product cp LEFT JOIN  " . DB_PREFIX . "cheaper_order_coupons coc using(coupon_id) WHERE coc.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cheaper_order_coupons  WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cheaper_order  WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
```

Comment: I think an OUTER JOIN on a DELETE is a little odd.

Comment: Also first line could be `DELETE c FROM coupon c`

Comment: Thank you Strawberry! Please post the whole line, because I don't know what should be replaced.

Comment: Why use a left join when you are looking for something on the 2nd table and deleting on the 1st table. It makes no sense. If it's not joined with anything then the column you're looking for will be `null`.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? mysql and sql-server are two different animals and could have a bearing on the answers given.

Comment: you're also trying to run a multi query and your server/RDBMS may not support it

Comment: there is a suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15132917 by an anonymous user wanting to remove the sql-server tag; again... which RDBMS are you using? I asked you 4-5 mins. prior to this comment.

Comment: Also, be aware that you can DELETE from multiple tables in a single query - and you can also use referential integrity (see CASCADE) - which simplifies the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

A valid query might look like this:

```
DELETE c -- assuming you only want to DELETE from coupon 
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "coupon c 
  JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "cheaper_order_coupons coc USING(coupon_id) 
 WHERE coc.order_id = $order_id;
```

Another example...

```
DELETE cp 
  FROM oc_coupon_product cp 
  JOIN oc_cheaper_order_coupons coc USING(coupon_id) 
 WHERE coc.order_id = 26
```

Comment: The OP is obviously trying to run a multi-query, which is probably why it's failing like that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure, bit I'm only addressing the specific error message

Comment: Well, the OP isn't responding to any of my comments up there, so it's anybody's ballgame really. They even asked you to post an example and didn't say a word about it here neither. So, wishing you well with this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I admit, it's not going very well at the moment - but maybe they have some narcoleptic condition, or something.

Comment: *ha ha!* - Maybe.

Comment: Ok i changed the query, but there still have error:

Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cp FROM oc_coupon_product cp LEFT JOIN oc_cheaper_order_coupons coc using(coupo' at line 1
Error No: 1064
DELETE oc_coupon_product cp FROM oc_coupon_product cp LEFT JOIN oc_cheaper_order_coupons coc using(coupon_id) WHERE coc.order_id = '26' in /home/vidraxfi/public_html/shop/system/database/mysql.php on line 50